# Trapping floating-point overflow in C

Tags: c, exception, floating-point

I am trying to trap floating-point overflow in C. Here is what I have tried

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <fenv.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void catch_overflow (int sig) {   
  printf ("caught division by zero\n");   
  signal (sig, catch_overflow); 
}


int main(void) {   
  feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO);   
  signal (FE_DIVBYZERO, catch_overflow);


  float a = 1., b = 0.;   float c = a/b;   return 0; }
```

I expected to see "caught division by zero" message, but I only get a core dump message, "Floating point exception (core dumped)". How could I modify the program to get the "caught division by zero" message?

Thanks.

Comment: If you catch SIGFPE instead, things work. But that doesn't answer your question, does it?

Comment: First, I did get "caught division by zero"  in that way, but I got them repeatedly output to the terminal that can only be terminated with ctrl-d. Also, why  fp_divbyzero does not work?

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO));` to see if that succeeded.

Comment: If you're going to access or modify the FP environment then you need to use [the `FENV_ACCESS` pragma](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.6.1) to tell the implementation about the region of your code that relies -- or may do -- on a non-default FP environment.  Undefined behavior ensues if your program attempts to access or modify the FP environment outside such a region.

Comment: Note also that if you trap floating-point exceptions in order to allow program execution to continue afterward, then you probably want the handler to clear the exception from the FP status.  That happens only if you do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

A floating point exception is translated in machine- and OS-dependent way to some signaling approach. But no such way allows mixing of different constant spaces, as FE_xxx and SIGxxx. Using `FE_DIVBYZERO` for signal(), you really caught `SIGILL` which is not generated for floating-point errors (because you did not specify OS, I was free to choose any - Linux in my case).

For your program, I have made this exception catching working under Linux with two changes:

1. Setting signal number to handle to `SIGFPE`.
2. Declaring `a, b, c` as volatile (prevents compiler from calculating `c` as `INF` at compile time).

After this, the program fell into eternal cycle printing "caught division by zero" because signal handler for such error restores execution to the same command. You shall carefully consider how to fix such errors without making an erroneous instruction eternal. For example, you can use `longjmp` to go out of signal handler to an installed exception handler.

And, you still should consult your target OS manuals for how to catch FP errors.

(This has been already described in comments in main parts - but I considered to form an explicit answer.)